# How to utilize Costmap in navigation process?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.

I'd like to use cost map of navigation precess, whose type is `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` .

When I tried checking how it looks like with `rostopic echo ~`, it seems the main information of cost map corresponds to `costmap.data` of [nav_msgs/Occupancy](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html)

But it has 100 X 100 lengths, so I wonder how can I access it.

What I want to do is simple:

> I want to convert the elements of `costmap.data` into Catesian-coordinate.

Anyone who knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342888/how-to-utilize-costmap-in-navigation-process?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2020-01-30**:
See the info field. It contains the origin and the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is in row-major order, The index is equal to the column + row * width.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1